# Can not link IBaction or IBOutlet

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, ibaction, iboutlet

when I try to create an IBOutlet or an IBAction by linking my interface to the header file, I don't get the option to create one.

Yeah, this COULD be a duplicate but I havent found my answer yet on ANY other post!

Thanks :)

```
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
- (IBAction)calculateClicked:(id)sender;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *ATextField;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *BTextField;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *CTextField;
```

Comment: Post code, please. Even if it's extremely straightforward property declarations, it'll help find a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what kind of object you wanted to add your outlets/actions to, but one might infer from the presence of the `window` reference that you're trying to add that to your app delegate. In that case, you just need to make sure that your app delegate appears in the list of objects, and that you've specified the base class for that app delegate:

[image: app delegate]

If, however, you were using some custom controller object, you would drag an generic object from the library to your NIB's list of objects. Then specify the custom controller class for that object (`MyController` in my example):

[image: Add controller to NIB]

Having done that, when you drag your outlets/actions from the window to the assistant editor, in addition to the app delegate, your custom controller object interface/implementation files will be options that you can use.

---

My original answer was an iOS-centric answer. The above should describe the Cocoa equivalent. I'll keep this original answer here for reference.

Original answer:

In Interface Builder, make sure to specify the base class for the object you're linking the outlets to. If putting these outlets in a view controller, make sure your storyboard's scene has the view controller's class defined. And it's a little easier if your assistant editor is set to "automatic":

[image: storyboard]

The above screen snapshot is relevant if you're using storyboards. If using NIBs, the idea is the same, but you need to make sure you set the NIB's file owner:

[image: NIB]

If your `IBOutlet` references are in a `UIView` subclass, you analogously have to specify the base class for your storyboard scene's view (or the NIB's view).

Comment: thanks but I'm not using a storyboard, I am using a standard project

Comment: It was set automatically. I just cant add either by linking, is this a bug?

Comment: @ANON Unlikely. Can you upload the project somewhere for us to look at it?

Comment: will upload, but how?

Comment: give me your email and i'll send you the project as an attachement

Comment: @ANON I've updated my answer for Cocoa-specific example. If you need to reach me, there is a link for me on my Stack Overflow profile. But hopefully the above answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen Xcode occasionally do this (bug).  Closing/reopening Xcode has fixed it for me before.

Also, make sure that your interface file is Class is pointing to this class/header.